# ASP.NET Pass value from javascript to code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass a value from javascript to a method in my code behind. I looked around online and the solution I got the most was using pagemethods. It doesn't seem to work for me so I think I may be doing it wrong. If there's another way to do this I would also like to hear it.

On my aspx file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In my javascript:

```
$("line").click(function () {
        PageMethods.ClickedOnLine(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    });
```

In code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void ClickedOnLine()
    {

    }
```

I put a breakpoint at the ClickedOnLine method but it doesn't fire.
How can I fix this?

Comment: By the way, I know the javascript click function is hit because I put a console.log there and it shows up whenever I click on the element.

Comment: Is your server side method hit? I don't know what "doesn't work" means. Why are you using page methods and web methods in 2017? Why not do Web API?

Comment: No my server side method is not hit. That's the problem. 
Why I'm using it? because this is what I found online. I'm not familiar with Web API.

Comment: Check out [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). Page methods and web methods trick you into thinking they can interact with the rest of the code behind since they're in the same class, but they can't. They also have given me quite a bit of trouble coercing them into supporting JSON. Also, all of John Saunder's [ASMX reasons](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) are applicable. (note that when he wrote that Web API wasn't around)

Comment: But I'm using a web forms project. Isn't there any way to do this without having to create a whole new project?

Comment: Sure. Just put it in the same project. Assuming you're not using years old frameworks, it all goes into one project just fine. Are you just starting out? If so, why are you starting with Web Forms and not MVC?

Comment: No I'm not just starting out. I have experience in both Web Forms and MVC, but the project I'm working on had been started in Web Forms a year or so ago so I wanted to continue that.

Comment: Ah, understandable. But I'd still avoid web methods. I would create a generic handler first

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with all of these terms. I created a web API project to see if I can move the project over. I was wondering if you could maybe help me with an example or concrete tutorials how to achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for a separate project. Just put it in the same one. It's just a matter of adding NuGet packages. I linked to tutorials above.

Comment: I'm playing around with it now. Do you happen to know how I could do the following: I want to resize something on my page according to the window size. I know window size is obtained in javascript, but is there a way to store those values so I can use them in a controller?

Comment: You'd just pass them from JavaScript back to the controller, as part of a form call or an AJAX method etc.